# What's a word between 'essentials' and 'subtleties'?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a plural noun describing a set of topics with an average importance/complexity, in the context of a learning environment? For a video game, I'm designing a sequence of three tutorials, with the first one explaining the basics and the other two going into progressively finer details. To indicate this to the player, I like the idea of calling the first one 'Essentials' and the last one 'Subtleties', but I'm struggling to find the right word for the middle one. It should basically mean 'moderately advanced topics', but I'd like to express that with a single-word, plural noun.

A sample sentence using the word that we're looking for would be:

> In this tutorial, you will learn the ____ of how to play this game.

The setting of the game is technological, futuristic.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: *specifics, particulars,* or a synonym thereof

Answer (score 1):

You used a suitable word in your question, and it's usually used in its plural form to denote a collection:

> In this tutorial, you will learn the **details** of how to play this
> game.

**detail** (n.)

> The **details** of something are its **individual features or elements**.
>
> *The details of the plan are still being worked out.
>
> No details of the discussions have been given.
>
> I recall every detail of the party.*
>
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/detail)

---

> These **essentials** are discussed in the order below. The **details**
> and the **finer points**, i.e., those that help tomake the difference
> between a really good brief and one that in merely adequate, are
> considered in Chapter 5.
> [Frederick Bernays Wiener et al; *Effective Appellate Advocacy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hEW4IqPp558C&pg=PA33&dq=essentials%20details%20finer%20points&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizyv2WqvKEAxVhFFkFHU8EBhEQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=essentials%20details%20finer%20points&f=false) (2004)

> To extend our foundation for the remaining chapters, we'll look at a
> few **essential** rules of Python syntax...After we've had more
> chances to work with simple and compound statements, the **detailed**
> syntax rules will make sense. [Steven Lott; *Python Essentials*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A0wOCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&dq=essentials%20details%20finer%20points&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTrp76rPKEAxV-FVkFHXKNC6c4ChDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=essentials%20details%20finer%20points&f=false)
> (2015)

**The Fine Points** might be an alternative title for the third topic.

Comment: Again, 'details' trivialises the question. 'What's a word between 'essentials' and 'subtleties': ... referring to average importance/complexity?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So a single word for [*meat and potatoes*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meat%20and%20potatoes) or [*nuts and bolts*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nuts%20and%20bolts)?

Comment: For [nuts and bolts](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/nuts-and-bolts), Collins Thesaurus gives nitty-gritty, practicalities, ins and outs, details (and because "nuts and bolts" means "the essential or practical details", other words meaning basics/fundamentals).

Answer (score 1):

The technicalities might sound too advanced.
The fundamentals could be viable if you named the first "the rudiments".

Although I think it is better to use "essentials" as your middle word and a more basic word in its place like "rudiments" based on this definition.

> The essentials are the most important principles, ideas, or facts of a
> particular subject. ...the essentials of everyday life, such as eating
> and exercise. [+ of] This has stripped the contest down to its
> essentials. ...the bare essentials.

From [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/essential)

It would then be :

The rudiments

The fundamentals/essentials

The subtleties/intricacies/technicalities